# Can't bind property since it is unknown property of button

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a problem where I have a module called `CoreModule` and it is imported in the `AppModule` and I am trying to use this module in some child module but if I import the module in the child module it gives this error `CoreModule has already been loaded. Import Core modules in the AppModule only.` when I go to the some component in that module.

If I don't import the `CoreModule` in child module it gives this error:`Can't bind to 'ngxHasAnyRole' since it isn't a known property of 'button'`

imports in my `AppModule` looks like this

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      level: NgxLoggerLevel.INFO,
      enableSourceMaps: true
    }),
  ],
```

My `CoreModule` look like this

```
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    NbAuthModule,
    HasRoleDirective,
    HasAnyRoleDirective,
  ],
  declarations: [HasAnyRoleDirective, HasRoleDirective],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<CoreModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        ...NB_CORE_PROVIDERS,
      ],
    };
  }
```

This is the part of the html where I try to use directive from `CoreModule`

```
        <button nbButton
                (click)="new()"
                [ngxHasAnyRole]="['ROLE_TEST', 'ROLE_ADMIN']"
                class="table-button"
                status="primary"
                size="small">
          NEW
          <nb-icon icon="plus-outline"></nb-icon>
        </button>
```

I don't want to import in the child module as this is imported in the Parent module. How can I fix this problem?

**Additional info**
When I do `ng serve` while having `CoreModule` imported in the child and then delete it while `ng serve` is on. It works but if I close and start again. It won't start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CoreModule` should be used for things that should only be imported once. These are usually imports from app wide services. What should definitely not go in a `CoreModule` are components, directives and pipes.

These are things that should go in a [`SharedModule`](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules).

There are several NgModule categories declared by angular, which you can use as a guideline:

- [Domain](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#domain): A domain NgModule is organized around a feature, business domain, or user experience.
- [Routed](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#routed): The top component of the NgModule acts as the destination of a router navigation route.
- [Routing](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#routing): A routing NgModule provides the routing configuration for another NgModule.
- [Service](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#service): A service NgModule provides utility services such as data access and messaging.
- [Widget](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#widget): A widget NgModule makes a component, directive, or pipe available to other NgModules.
- [Shared](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#shared): A shared NgModule makes a set of components, directives, and pipes available to other NgModules.

My advice is to really read the excellent docs/guides provided on [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs)

So what do you have to do? Remove the export and declarations of `HasAnyRoleDirective` and `HasRoleDirective` from your `CoreModule` and place these in a `SharedModule` or create a small module `RoleModule` and only import this where necessary. Up to you

Comment: In addition to your answer, models also can be defined inside the Shared module!

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Are you talking about Data models? I guess you can put them in the same physical directory, but you cannot add them to the `@NgModule` declaration

Comment: Yeah, I know, what I mean that your Shared module should contain, pipes, directives, components, and data models!